# Ignore SCRT2 Integration User Permission Set

Tags: salesforcedx, .forceignore

I'm trying to .forceignore SCRT2 Integration User permission set but it's not working and keeps being retrieved. If I add the same entry to .gitignore its removed from source control. Any idea why it works for .gitignore but not .forceignore?

```
.forceignore - doesn't work
**/sfdcInternalInt__*.permissionset-meta.xml

.gitignore - works
**/sfdcInternalInt__*.permissionset-meta.xml
```

Comment: I also tried `**/permissionsets/sfdcInternalInt__sfdc_scrt2.permissionset-meta.xml` in forceignore and that didn't work either